# There is a gap between android action bar and tabs. why?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created custom layout for actionbar which has Tabview. But there is a gap between action bar and tabs in black. Kindly see the below image. I am using theme Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar
Target SDK: 19
Please help.

style.xml is as below:

```
<!-- Application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarSize">36dip</item>
    </style>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
    android:id="@+id/sliding_tabs"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:theme="@style/MyCustomTabLayout"
    app:tabBackground="@android:color/holo_orange_dark"
    app:tabIndicatorColor="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
    app:tabTextColor="@android:color/white"
    app:tabSelectedTextColor="@android:color/black"/>

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/viewpager"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0px"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:background="@android:color/white" />
```

custom action bar

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_orange_dark">
<Spinner
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/spinnerActionBar" />
```

Comment: Consider using the new Toolbar instead of a Custom View. Anyways, try to use `wrap_content` as height and width for your custom view, instead of `match_parent`.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use **Toolbar** as **ActionBar** is **deprecate** now. you can have more functionality than ActionBar.

here is [example](https://mzgreen.github.io/2015/02/28/How-to-hideshow-Toolbar-when-list-is-scrolling%28part2%29/) like you need to use

Answer (score 0):

I remember having this trouble before. Try adding the contentInsets in the xml.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    ...
    app:contentInsetStart="0dp"
    app:contentInsetEnd="0dp"    
/>
```